# Date incorrectly interpreted in my string

Tags: javascript

I have the following javascript code:

```
var myDate = new Date("10/04/2013");
var d = myDate.getDate();
var m = myDate.getMonth();
var y = myDate.getFullYear();
```

When I debug this code I got:

d = 4

m = 9

y = 2013

This is not was I expected. I would like to interpret my date as day / month / year.

How to proceed?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a date adaptor, which converts you date type to a proper JS date object. Some thing like this -

```
var myDateAdapter  = function(str){
var d = new Date();
var k = str.split('/');
d.setDate(k[0]);
d.setMonth(k[1]-1);
d.setFullYear(k[2]);
return d;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Months are `0` indexed in JavaScript.

Here is the MDN documentation for it.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Comment: Ok that's good to know but my problem is also that my string '10/04/2013' is interpreted as month / day / year but I was expecting day / month / year.

Comment: @Bronzato that's because javascript doesn't have culture when specifying a date.

Answer (score 1):

Get day, month and year using split function and construct date.

```
function myDateFormat(dateString) {
    var splited = dateString.split("/");
    return (new Date(splited[2],splited[1] - 1, splited[0]));
}

var myDate = myDateFormat("10/04/2013");
```

Hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Date.parseEx = function (d) {
    var r = /(\d+)\/(\d+)\/(\d+)/;
    if (r.test(d)) {
        var m = d.match(r);
        return new Date(m[3], m[1] - 1, m[2]);
    }
    return null;
}
```

Then:

```
var myDate = Date.parseEx("10/04/2013");
if (myDate) {
    var d = myDate.getDate();
    var m = myDate.getMonth();
    var y = myDate.getFullYear();
}
```